# Callback not executing on a "passed in viewController pointer" to another class

Tags: objective-c

The following code draws the buttons when I pass in the viewController pointer.  But the callback is never executed.  However, when I change the "button" "setTarget" from self to the viewController pointer I get the following CrashReport.

```
 //ViewController Code portion
 MenuButtons *mbMenu = [MenuButtons alloc];
 [mbMenu initMe:self.view]; // <-- viewController Pointer view "self.view"
```

---

```
 @implementation MenuButtons


 - (void)initMe:(NSView*)p. //p is the pointer to the viewController passed in here.
 {
     NSButton *nsbSolve = [[NSButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 10, 400, 80)];
     [p addSubview:nsbSolve];
     [nsbSolve setButtonType:NSMomentaryPushInButton];
     [nsbSolve setTarget:self];   // <-- replace with "p" and I get the crash report below --- 
     [nsbSolve setAction:@selector(callbackSolve)];
     [nsbSolve setTitle:@"Solve"];
}

 - (void) callbackSolve{
     NSLog(@"callbackSolve");

     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"updatePageVisible" object:nil];
 }
```

@end

---

CrashReport

```
-[NSView callbackSolve]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6100001212c0
```

XXX[2914:218080] [General] -[NSView callbackSolve]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6100001212c0

Comment: you are calling callbackSolve on NSView which doesnt exist. It exists on the view controller but not on view.

Comment: replace self.view with self

Comment: works as long as I put the callback methods in the viewController and not in  the menuButton class